# C makefile RE: build dependencies to properly find objects in their respective directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile for a C project.  I have the src in a directory thusly named with some of the source in a sub-dir off src.  Includes are in an include dir off src.

In the Makefile, I'm using the following to generate dependency info for the .c source files:

```
%.o: %.c
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(STACK_OPTS) $(SIO_FLAGS) $(IO_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES) -DSYNC_WRITE $<
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES)  $^ > $*.d
    @cp -f $*.d $*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
      sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d
    @rm -f $*.d.tmp
```

This works fine...however, that I'm finding is that those source files in the sub-dir off of src have their .d and .o files deposited in the main src directory INSTEAD of having them put in the directory where the source file is for it.

I've played with the macros $( < D)  in an attempt to store the object (.o) and dependency files (.d) prepending the directory name where they should be but when the link stage occurs it isn't finding the files in this directory.

I have a VPATH setup with the directory named.

thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Wish I knew how to help you. `Make` is something of a black art to me. One suggestion: any time I've had to do something with `make`, it always helped me to know **exactly** how to make `gcc` do what I wanted from the command line first. Then I worked on the makefile. Good luck.

Comment: OK, progress, I used the vpath (lowercase) to specify where to look for the source file, include AND had forgotten to include a separate group of object files using:
-include $(MYOBJS:.o=.d)

Now, it is finding stuff where it actually exists...

In the linking stage gcc is not finding the objects in the subdirs...so...is there a vpath equivalent?  I guess what should be happening here is the object files should be rewritten when the object is actually found in a subdirectory.

Comment: I believe the problem is the use of the automatic var $^ in the TARGETS build rule.  Is there some magic make sorcery here to force it to look in the vpath dirs for where the object files ACTUALLY are?

Comment: Here is the TARGETS rule:

$(TARGETS):
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"
    $(CC) $(OAK_LIBS) -o $@ $^ $(ISAM_FLAGS) $(CSCAPE_LIBS) $(NET_LIBS) $(WINDOWING_LIB) $(TOOLS_LIB)
    @cp $@ ../bin

Answer (score 1):

By default VPATH will put all targets into the current working directory.  The standard use for VPATH is a mode where you have a read-only source directory and you want to build your objects somewhere else; for example you need to compile multiple times with different flags or whatever.  Then you make the object directory your current directory and run the makefile so that it finds the sources with VPATH.

If you want the targets to go in the same directory as the prerequisites, you can add `GPATH` use to your `VPATH` use; check the GNU make manual for details.

Comment: I just tried setting GPATH too...still blows up in building the TARGETS.  Curiously, if I run make again, it goes further.  So, it would appear the $^ in the TARGET rule is not correctly using the expansion / dir lookup to where the VPATH denotes they should be.

Comment: I think what is foobarring the TARGET rule is my using $(<D)/$@ in the rule to generate the object in the respective dir where the source file is located.  Trying to keep stuff neat and tidy.  But this breaks the TARGET rule $^ in that it doesn't (the first time anyway) substitute the correct dir into the objects location.

Comment: Correct.  You almost never want to write a recipe that doesn't create the target file exactly as make thinks it should be created, which is `$@`.  If you use GPATH then `$@` will keep the directory found by vpath, and you won't need to change it.